# How do I reverse a promise?

Tags: swift, promisekit

I'm using [PromiseKit](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit) to handle flow through a process.

Prior, I did a similar app without promises but decided frick it I'm gonna try promises just because, well, why not?

So I'm throwing a back button in the mix as I did in the prior app. Only problem is, I'm not exactly sure how to handle "reversing" if you want to call it that.

So say I have a flow of

```
doSomething().then {
    // do something else 
}.then { 
    // do something else 
}.done { 
    // wrap it up, boss
}.catch { 
   // you're an idiot, bud 
}
```

Say I'm in the first or second part of the chain then and I want to go back up the chain - is this possible?

Is there a link y'all can give me that I can use to read up on how to do that?

I'm thinking I might have to restart the "chain", but then how would I step through the flow....WAIT (light bulb), I can programmatically fulfill the necessary promises with whatever the data is that initially was fulfilled with until I get to the point in the "chain" where I needed to go back to, right?

Advice D:?

Comment: What you're describing doesn't seem possible.  Do you have a concrete example of the behavior you're trying to achieve?

Comment: You can always throw and catch in whatever closure you want.

Comment: By saving a reference to a promise, you can always fire off different chains of events.  Wrote an example as my answer below.

Comment: An example of what you're trying to achieve would be very helpful for us to help you with this answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can always have a `catch` and a `then` on the same promise.

```
var somePromise = doSomething()

// first chain
somePromise.catch { error in 
    // handle error 
}

// second chain from the same starting point
somePromise.then { 
    // do something else
}.then { 
   // do something else 
}.catch {
    // you can still catch the error here too
}
```

You're basically creating two promise chains from the same original promise.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can not do that. Once you commit a `promise`, you can not reverse that. Because the chain is supposed to finish in the descending order, it's cumbersome to track the order in each `.then` block.

What you can do is, handle the internal logic responsible to `fulfill` or `reject` a `promise` and start the chain from the beginning.

```
func executeChain() {

    doSomething().then {
        // do something else 
    }.then { 
        // do something else 
    }.done { 
        // condition to 
        executeChain()
    }.catch { 
        // you're an idiot, bud 
    }
}

func doSomething() -> Promise<SomeThing>{

    if (condition to bypass for reversing) {
        return .value(something)
    }

    // Normal execution
}
```

But if you can improve your question with an actual use case and code then it could help providing more suitable explanation.

Answer (score 0):

No you can't but you can set order in array.

```
bar(promises: [foo1(), foo2(), foo3()])


func bar<T>(promises: [Promise<T>]) {

    when(fulfilled: promises)
    .done { _ in
        // TODO
    }
    .catch { error in
        // When get error reverse array and call it again
        self.bar(promises: promises.reversed())
    }

}

func foo1() -> Promise<Void> {
    return Promise { $0.fulfill(()) }
}

func foo2() -> Promise<Void> {
    return Promise { $0.fulfill(()) }
}

func foo3() -> Promise<Void> {
    return Promise { $0.fulfill(()) }
}
```

or alternatively

```
    bar(foo1, foo2, foo3)
    .done { _ in
        // TODO
    }
    .catch { error in
        print(error.localizedDescription)

        self.bar(self.foo3, self.foo2, self.foo1)
        .done { _ in
            // TODO
        }
        .catch { error2 in
            print(error2.localizedDescription)
        }
    }


    func bar<T>(_ promise1: () -> Promise<T>,
                _ promise2: @escaping () -> Promise<T>,
                _ promise3: @escaping () -> Promise<T>) -> Promise<T> {

        return Promise { seal in
            promise1()
            .then { _ in return promise2() }
            .then { _ in return promise3() }
            .done { model in
                seal.fulfill(model)
            }
            .catch {
                seal.reject($0)
            }
        }

    }

    func foo1() -> Promise<Void> {
        return Promise { $0.fulfill(()) }
    }

    func foo2() -> Promise<Void> {
        return Promise { $0.fulfill(()) }
    }

    func foo3() -> Promise<Void> {
        return Promise { $0.fulfill(()) }
    }
```